# Passing int between 3 classes in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have 3 classes namely GameScene, HomeScene and RecordsScene and I am trying to pass an integer value from GameScene to the RecordScene. My problem is, once the game is done, it goes home, then you have to click on Records to see the Records. Basically, the order of the three classes would be something like this:

GameScene --> HomeScene --> RecordScene

What I've been trying to do was pass the integer value from GameScene to the HomeScene then from the HomeScene, I'll pass it to the RecordScene but when I get there, the value of the integer is still 0. Here's my current code:

```
//GameScene
-(void)goHome:(ccTime)dt
{
HomeScene *home = [HomeScene node];
//myInt is an integer I declared on the HomeScene class, the value changes depending on the stage
home.layer.myInt = 1;
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:home];}

//HomeScene
-(void)viewRecord:(id)sender
{
//View record
RecordScene *record = [RecordScene node];
//lastStage is the integer from RecordScene I'm passing the value of myInt into
record.layer.lastStage = myInt;
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:record];}
```

I'm implementing the classes like so:

```
@implementation HomeScene
@synthesize layer;

-(id)init
{
if((self =[super init]))
{
    self.layer = [HomeSceneLayer node];
    [self addChild:layer];
}
return self;
}
@end

@implementation HomeSceneLayer
@synthesize myInt;
//methods
@end
```

Then my header looks something like so:

```
@interface HomeScene : CCLayer
{
int myInt;}
@property(nonatomic)int myInt;
@end

@interface HomeScene : CCScene
{
HomeSceneLayer *layer;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)HomeSceneLayer *layer;
@end
```

Why is it resetting back to 0 and how do I pass the integer value from the GameScene to the RecordScene?

Comment: How do you declare the `layer` property on `HomeScene`, and `myInt` on `layer` ? Do you use ARC? If not have you made sure the instance is not released before you obtain the int value?

Comment: Basically, what I did was implement HomeScene and synthesize layer to add layer. Then I implemented HomeSceneLayer and synthesized myInt there. I'll update my post to include the post for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@synthesize myInt;` creates an iVar `_myInt`.

```
RecordScene *record = [RecordScene node];
//lastStage is the integer from RecordScene I'm passing the value of myInt into
record.layer.lastStage = myInt;
```

you are setting `record.layer.lastStage` to myInt (iVar of HomeScene). Try `record.layer.lastStage = self.layer.myInt;`

From Apple's coding guidelines at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html

> Make sure the name of the instance variable concisely describes the attribute stored. Usually, you should not access instance variables directly, instead you should use accessor methods (you do access instance variables directly in init and dealloc methods). To help to signal this, prefix instance variable names with an underscore (_), for example:

Xcode now (I don't know since when) also synthesizes properties automatically, naming the iVar for `@property [...] foo` `_foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try but record still returns 0

Comment: your are setting `home.layer.myInt = 1;` and then try to access myInt in HomeScene. Try `record.layer.lastStage = self.layer.myInt;`. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by just removing the RecordScene and add a method that would remove all the children from the HomeScene and add everything that was supposed to be on the RecordScene. Kinda like, a layer on top of the HomeScene. It's a bit tedious though, as I had to make modifications for my other classes. I'm far from done so I'll still give this a try. Thank you so much! :)